# File 'main.run.xml' not created by logreq error

Tags: biblatex, biber, logreq

I use `biblatex` which I believe loads `logreq` and I am getting error:

`Error:(152) logreq: File 'main.run.xml' not created by logreq.`

The temporary fix is that I delete `main.run.xml` between runs. This is rather annoying and instead I would love to just disable `logreq` because as far as I know, it's facilities are not really needed. Any insight as to what might be going on? I can't reproduce this with a MWE, it came out of nowhere it seems.

Here is the logreq:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- logreq request file -->
<!-- logreq version 1.0 / dtd version 1.0 -->
<!-- Do not edit this file! -->
<!DOCTYPE requests [
  <!ELEMENT requests (internal | external)*>
  <!ELEMENT internal (generic, (provides | requires)*)>
  <!ELEMENT external (generic, cmdline?, input?, output?, (provides | requires)*)>
  <!ELEMENT cmdline (binary, (option | infile | outfile)*)>
  <!ELEMENT input (file)+>
  <!ELEMENT output (file)+>
  <!ELEMENT provides (file)+>
  <!ELEMENT requires (file)+>
  <!ELEMENT generic (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT binary (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT option (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT infile (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT outfile (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT file (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST requests
    version CDATA #REQUIRED
  >
  <!ATTLIST internal
    package CDATA #REQUIRED
    priority (9) #REQUIRED
    active (0 | 1) #REQUIRED
  >
  <!ATTLIST external
    package CDATA #REQUIRED
    priority (1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8) #REQUIRED
    active (0 | 1) #REQUIRED
  >
  <!ATTLIST provides
    type (static | dynamic | editable) #REQUIRED
  >
  <!ATTLIST requires
    type (static | dynamic | editable) #REQUIRED
  >
  <!ATTLIST file
    type CDATA #IMPLIED
  >
]>
<requests version="1.0">
  <internal package="biblatex" priority="9" active="0">
    <generic>latex</generic>
    <provides type="dynamic">
      <file>main.bcf</file>
    </provides>
    <requires type="dynamic">
      <file>main.bbl</file>
    </requires>
    <requires type="static">
      <file>blx-dm.def</file>
      <file>blx-unicode.def</file>
      <file>blx-compat.def</file>
      <file>biblatex.def</file>
      <file>standard.bbx</file>
      <file>numeric.bbx</file>
      <file>numeric.cbx</file>
      <file>biblatex.cfg</file>
      <file>english.lbx</file>
      <file>canadian.lbx</file>
    </requires>
  </internal>
  <external package="biblatex" priority="5" active="0">
    <generic>biber</generic>
    <cmdline>
      <binary>biber</binary>
      <infile>main</infile>
    </cmdline>
    <input>
      <file>main.bcf</file>
    </input>
    <output>
      <file>main.bbl</file>
    </output>
    <provides type="dynamic">
      <file>main.bbl</file>
    </provides>
    <requires type="dynamic">
      <file>main.bcf</file>
    </requires>
  </external>
</requests>
```

Comment: make a bit of an effort to come up with some details. For example look into the xml and try to figure out why logreq thinks it doesn't produce it.

Comment: See edit. I don't really see how anything but logreq is producing this.

Comment: Why the downvotes and close requests? Like I said, I'm not getting this error with a MWE. I have a massive class file and it would be tedious to track down this error. I'm shooting my shot to see if anyone else has encountered this issue. The main.run.xml file looks to be created by logreq.

Comment: I didn't downvote and didn't flag. But as it is it isn't possible to say what happens for you (and I wouldn't be sure that the file is not needed, biblatex is using it in various places.)

Comment: Hey Ulrike, that wasn't necessarily directed at you. Thanks for the additional input, though. Will see how my document is affected.

Comment: "I'm not getting this error with a MWE" but you are getting it with "a massive class file" means that you can perform a binary search to figure out what is causing the problem.  Copy everything over to a new project and start deleting.  Find out what causes the change from not working to working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a lualatex user and adding this to the pre-amble was easy. Doesn't find the root cause of the issue though.

```
\begin{luacode*}
  os.remove('./out/main.run.xml')
\end{luacode*}
```